# Не получается вернуть значение ajax-запроса

Tags: jquery

Делаю ajax-запрос к API, но вместо json-объекта возвращается `undefined`:

```
return JSON.parse($.ajax({
    url: '//autocomplete.travelpayouts.com/jravia?locale=ru&with_countries=false&q=' + $('#takeoff_place').val(),
    type: 'GET',
    dataType: 'json'
}).responseText);
```

Что я делаю не так?

Comment: В момент выполнения return ещё не завершилось выполнение $.ajax()

Answer (score 0):

Чем не устраивает такой вариант?

```
$.getJSON('autocomplete.travelpayouts.com/jravia?locale=ru&with_countries=false&q=' + $('#takeoff_place').val(), function( json ) {
     console.log(json);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>

  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script>
    $(document).ready(function() {
      $("#load").click(function() {
      
        var settings = {
          "async": true,
          "crossDomain": true,
          "url": "http://autocomplete.travelpayouts.com/jravia?locale=ru&with_countries=false&q="+$("#takeoff_place").val(),
          "method": "GET"
        }

        $.ajax(settings).done(function(response) {
          console.log(response);
        });


      })


    })
  </script>
</head>

<body>
  <input id="takeoff_place" placeholder="Введите город :)"><br>
  <a id="load" href="#">Load</a>


</body>

</html>
```